# With Unity how do I inject a InjectionConstructor into a closed source API (Lucene)

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm quite new to DI and IoC so as you can imagine I'm starting to hit some walls getting this application going now with a Unity container. The problem is when I want to use DI on the `StandardAnalyzer` in Lucene, I'm getting the following error:

> The type StandardAnalyzer has multiple constructors of length 2.
>   Unable to disambiguate.

So what I understand is, is the Unity Container is looking for the constructor with the most parameters but because there is multiple it can't tell which one. The constructor though as you will see in my code below is just wanting to use the one with one parameter with a type of Version (from the Lucene namespace). I've tried using `InjectionConstructor` but can't get it to work, and I'm starting to think it might not be possible. Any help please?

```
private const string Analyzer = "analyzer";
private const string Logging = "logging";
private const string FsDirectory = "fsDirectory"; 
private const string IndexWriter =   "indexWriter";

var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
var fsDirectory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(
    new AppConfig().DatabaseName()));
var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(fsDirectory, analyzer, 
    new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(int.MaxValue));

this.RegisterType<StandardAnalyzer>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedParameter<Version>(Analyzer)));
//RegisterInstance(typeof(StandardAnalyzer), Analyzer, analyzer, 
//    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
RegisterInstance(typeof(FSDirectory), FsDirectory, fsDirectory, 
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
RegisterInstance(typeof(IndexWriter), IndexWriter, indexWriter, 
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

this.RegisterType<IDocumentIndexerWithLucene, DocumentIndexerWithLucene>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter(typeof(StandardAnalyzer), Analyzer),
        new ResolvedParameter(typeof(Logging), Logging), 
        new ResolvedParameter(typeof(FSDirectory), FsDirectory),
        new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IndexWriter), IndexWriter)));
```

Comment: What does your comment mean? Please update your question if appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

For static dependencies (types that are in a external library or .NET framework) you should typically not use auto-wiring (automatic constructor injection), but register a delegate that creates that type. Automatic constuctor injection helps making your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) more maintainable, because this allows you to change the constructor of types without having to make changes to your composition root. Static dependencies on the other hand don't change that often, so maintainability is not an issue their. On the other hand, static dependencies are often not DI friendly and can contain multiple constructors which can make auto-wiring much harder (as you are experiencing). To make things worse, even when you get auto-wiring working on a static type, a upgrading to newer version of that external could break your composition root, since a new constructor can be introduced (and this proves that [every change is a breaking change](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change.aspx)) that are incompatible with your DI container.

So the solution is to register a delegate that manually creates that type:

```
container.Register<IService>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
    new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29)));
```